# Why Sublime Text is suddenly NOT HIGHLIGHTING the selected text until i release the mouse button?

Tags: selection, highlighting

I am assuming that I inadvertently pressed a key command that changed a setting, but I cant find it.

Using Windows 10, when I drag to select text, there is no highlighting until I get to the end and release the mouse button, at which point the text I had dragged over becomes highlighted.

Comment: Hello, could you show how exactly it looks? Are you using the default theme/color scheme? Which extensions do you have?

Comment: I'm using the default theme/color scheme. No extentions have been added.  Thank you

Comment: Now it seems to be working normally!  I think it may have been "fixed" by a reboot or conflicting other software?

Comment: Well, perhaps a bug then, should report it here https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text. I had a quick look at settings/keybinding yesterday and there doesn't seem to be anything related to the selection highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (while click+drag selecting text the text was not highlighted until the mouse button was released) and for me the issue was a "Thank you for trying sublime text, would you like to purchase it?" window had opened behind the sublime window.

Closing this window fixed the problem for me.